# How to check password strength?

Tags: .net, security, cryptography, passwords

How can I check the strength of a password (as a `string`) using the .Net Framework?

Comment: Do the ones you've found produce consistent and comparable results?

Comment: What is your criteria for strength? Can you be more explicit about what you want to test for?

Comment: My criteria would be entropy - none of the answers satisfies that one. According to [this question on crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/374/how-should-i-calculate-the-entropy-of-a-password) Shannon is the theoretical solution. In practice you also have to eliminate everything from a dictionary/wikipedia/technical language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basic but a logical one:

```
enum PasswordScore
{
    Blank = 0,
    VeryWeak = 1,
    Weak = 2,
    Medium = 3,
    Strong = 4,
    VeryStrong = 5
}

public class PasswordAdvisor
{
    public static PasswordScore CheckStrength(string password)
    {
        int score = 1;

        if (password.Length < 1)
            return PasswordScore.Blank;
        if (password.Length < 4)
            return PasswordScore.VeryWeak;

        if (password.Length >= 8)
            score++;
        if (password.Length >= 12)
            score++;
        if (Regex.Match(password, @"/\d+/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript))
            score++;
        if (Regex.Match(password, @"/[a-z]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript) &&
            Regex.Match(password, @"/[A-Z]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript))
            score++;
        if (Regex.Match(password, @"/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,£,(,)]/",  RegexOptions.ECMAScript))
            score++;

        return (PasswordScore)score;
    }
}
```

Ref: http://passwordadvisor.com/CodeAspNet.aspx

Comment: `password123` is a medium password? A bit better when you start score at 0 instead of 1. Better use something like https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn

Answer (score 10):

"Password strength" is a rather generic term, it could mean password character count, range of characters used (cardinality), time needed to crack (brute force) the password, etc..

One of the best ways to measure a password's cryptographic strength would be to calculate how many bits of [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) the password has (although, this is generally more accurate for measuring *random* passwords. You'll get an *over* estimated entropy result otherwise),

```
// Only accurate for passwords in ASCII.
public double CalculateEntropy(string password)
{
    var cardinality = 0;

    // Password contains lowercase letters.
    if (password.Any(c => char.IsLower(c)))
    {
        cardinality = 26;
    }

    // Password contains uppercase letters.
    if (password.Any(c => char.IsUpper(c)))
    {
        cardinality += 26;
    }

    // Password contains numbers.
    if (password.Any(c => char.IsDigit(c)))
    {
        cardinality += 10;
    }

    // Password contains symbols.
    if (password.IndexOfAny("\\|¬¦`!\"£$%^&*()_+-=[]{};:'@#~<>,./? ".ToCharArray()) >= 0)
    {
        cardinality += 36;
    }

    return Math.Log(cardinality, 2) * password.Length;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple one I've written:

```
/// <summary>
/// Evaluates a password
/// </summary>
public class PasswordEvaluator
{
    public string Password { get; private set; }
    public int Length { get; private set; }
    public int TotalNumberChars { get; private set; }
    public bool ContainsNumberChars{get { return TotalNumberChars > 0; }}
    public int TotalUppercaseChars { get; private set; }
    public bool ContainsUppercaseChars { get { return TotalUppercaseChars > 0; } }
    public int TotalLowercaseChars { get; private set; }
    public bool ContainsLowercaseChars { get { return TotalLowercaseChars > 0; } }
    public int TotalSpecialChars { get; private set; }
    public bool ContainsSpecialChars { get { return TotalSpecialChars > 0; } }

    public PasswordEvaluator(string password)
    {
        Password = password.Trim();
        Length = Password.Length;
        foreach (var c in Password)
        {
            var charCode = (int)c;
            if (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) TotalNumberChars++;
            else if (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90) TotalUppercaseChars++;
            else if (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122) TotalLowercaseChars++;
            else TotalSpecialChars++;
        }
    }
    public bool StrongEnough()
    {
        // Minimum length requirement
        if (Length < Settings.PasswordMinLength) return false;

        // Mixed case requirement
        if (!ContainsLowercaseChars && !ContainsUppercaseChars) return false;

        // Special chars requirement
        if (TotalSpecialChars < 3) return false;

        // Min lower case chars requirement
        if (TotalLowercaseChars < 3) return false;

        // Min upper case chars requirement
        if (TotalUppercaseChars < 3) return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

You can define your own rules in `StrongEnough()`

Comment: This is far superior to many of the other answers, or at least something derived from this kind of implementation. The desired thing is to get an object that *records useful information* about the password, from which someone can make informed decisions. While it's not really that important in this case (not even remotely a bottleneck), this way is vastly more performant as well. I see regex implementations above that repeatedly test if a letter of a certain case exists by rerunning the regex! Better is to get the information once: Is there an upper case, etc. Other checks can still be added:

Comment: Such as: `passwd.match(/(\d.*\d)/)`- I think this check from one of the answers above is asking: Does a digit or more ever occur, followed by another digit (however, this regex may actually be matched by two digits in a row, you could re-write with ! in between). In this c# case, one could figure this out without a regex, recording: Do an upper case occur more than once broken by not an uppercase, and the same thing for lower case and number. Anyways, this is vastly the better way to go, you then have a record to make decisions upon.

Answer (score 5):

If I may show my customized implementation of examples such as Teoman Soygul's (and others I've seen similar to his)...  My implementation has a different scoring scheme and uses minimum requirements as well as a check for repeating characters.

```
public enum PasswordScore
{
    Blank = 0,
    TooShort = 1,
    RequirementsNotMet = 2,
    VeryWeak = 3,
    Weak = 4,
    Fair = 5,
    Medium = 6,
    Strong = 7,
    VeryStrong = 8
}

public static PasswordScore CheckStrength(string password)
    {
        int score = 0;

        // using three requirements here:  min length and two types of characters (numbers and letters)
        bool blnMinLengthRequirementMet = false;
        bool blnRequirement1Met = false;
        bool blnRequirement2Met = false;

        // check for chars in password
        if (password.Length < 1)
            return PasswordScore.Blank;

        // if less than 6 chars, return as too short, else, plus one
        if (password.Length < 6)
        {
            return PasswordScore.TooShort;
        }
        else
        {
            score++;
            blnMinLengthRequirementMet = true;
        }

        // if 8 or more chars, plus one
        if (password.Length >= 8)
            score++;

        // if 10 or more chars, plus one
        if (password.Length >= 10)
            score++;

        // if password has a number, plus one
        if (Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[\d]", RegexOptions.ECMAScript))
        {
            score++;
            blnRequirement1Met = true;
        }

        // if password has lower case letter, plus one
        if (Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[a-z]", RegexOptions.ECMAScript))
        {
            score++;
            blnRequirement2Met = true;
        }

        // if password has upper case letter, plus one
        if (Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[A-Z]", RegexOptions.ECMAScript))
        {
            score++;
            blnRequirement2Met = true;
        }

        // if password has a special character, plus one
        if (Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[~`!@#$%\^\&\*\(\)\-_\+=\[\{\]\}\|\\;:'\""<\,>\.\?\/£]", RegexOptions.ECMAScript))
            score++;

        // if password is longer than 2 characters and has 3 repeating characters, minus one (to minimum of score of 3)
        List<char> lstPass = password.ToList();
        if (lstPass.Count >= 3)
        {
            for (int i = 2; i < lstPass.Count; i++)
            {
                char charCurrent = lstPass[i];
                if (charCurrent == lstPass[i - 1] && charCurrent == lstPass[i - 2] && score >= 4)
                {
                    score++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!blnMinLengthRequirementMet || !blnRequirement1Met || !blnRequirement2Met)
        {
            return PasswordScore.RequirementsNotMet;
        }

        return (PasswordScore)score;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple JavaScript example of what I use, porting it to .Net shouldn't be very hard,

```
    var getStrength = function (passwd) {
    intScore = 0;
    intScore = (intScore + passwd.length);
    if (passwd.match(/[a-z]/)) {
        intScore = (intScore + 1);
    }
    if (passwd.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
        intScore = (intScore + 5);
    }
    if (passwd.match(/\d+/)) {
        intScore = (intScore + 5);
    }
    if (passwd.match(/(\d.*\d)/)) {
        intScore = (intScore + 5);
    }
    if (passwd.match(/[!,@#$%^&*?_~]/)) {
        intScore = (intScore + 5);
    }
    if (passwd.match(/([!,@#$%^&*?_~].*[!,@#$%^&*?_~])/)) {
        intScore = (intScore + 5);
    }
    if (passwd.match(/[a-z]/) && passwd.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
        intScore = (intScore + 2);
    }
    if (passwd.match(/\d/) && passwd.match(/\D/)) {
        intScore = (intScore + 2);
    }
    if (passwd.match(/[a-z]/) && passwd.match(/[A-Z]/) && passwd.match(/\d/) && passwd.match(/[!,@#$%^&*?_~]/)) {
        intScore = (intScore + 2);
    }
    return intScore;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my own code used towards a password strength checker based on information entropy and NIST guidelines. However this method does not account for the 'human' language factor.

```
public enum PasswordScore
{
    Blank,
    VeryWeak,
    Weak,
    Medium,
    Strong,
    VeryStrong
}

public static PasswordScore CheckPasswordStrength(string password)
{
    int N = 0;
    int L = password.Length;
    if (L == 0)
        return PasswordScore.Blank;
    if (Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[\d]", RegexOptions.ECMAScript))
        N += 10;
    if (Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[a-z]", RegexOptions.ECMAScript))
        N += 26;
    if (Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[A-Z]", RegexOptions.ECMAScript))
        N += 26;
    if (Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[~`!@#$%\^\&\*\(\)\-_\+=\[\{\]\}\|\\;:'\""<\,>\.\?\/£]", RegexOptions.ECMAScript) && password.Length > 8)
        N += 33;
    int H = Convert.ToInt32(L * (Math.Round(Math.Log(N) / Math.Log(2))));
    if (H <= 32) return PasswordScore.VeryWeak;
    if (H <= 48) return PasswordScore.Weak;
    if (H <= 64) return PasswordScore.Medium;
    if (H <= 80) return PasswordScore.Strong;
    return PasswordScore.VeryStrong;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strength of a password should be checked on behalf of several parameters like the presence of special characters and numbers, length of the password etc.

I have found the below tutorial with nice demo:

http://tinytute.com/2014/06/03/animated-password-strength-checker-quick-easy/

The jQuery code block:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#textBox").keyup(function(){

        var passWord = $("#textBox").val();
        var passLength = passWord.length;
        var specialFlag = 0;
        var numberFlag = 0;
        var numberGenerator = 0;
        var total = 0;

        if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(passWord) == false) {

            specialFlag =20;
        }


        if(passWord.match(/[0-9]/)) {

            numberFlag = 25;
        }

        if(passLength>4&&passLength<=6){
            numberGenerator =25;
        }else if(passLength>=7&&passLength<=9){
            numberGenerator =35;
        }else if(passLength>9){
            numberGenerator =55;
        }else if(passLength>0&&passLength<=4){
            numberGenerator =15;
        }else{
            numberGenerator =0;
        }

        total = numberGenerator + specialFlag + numberFlag;
        if(total<30){
            $('#progressBar').css('background-color','#CCC');
        }else if(total<60&&total>=30){

            $('#progressBar').css('background-color','#FF6600');

        }else if(total>=60&&total<90){

            $('#progressBar').css('background-color','#FFCC00');

        }else if(total>=90){

            $('#progressBar').css('background-color','#0f0');

        }
        $('#progressBar').css('width',total+'%');

    });

});
```