# Not able to access Enum from another class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, enums

I'm implementing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151576/password-strength-checker-net) in VB.NET by attempting to use the implementation methodology [here](http://passwordadvisor.com/CodeAspNet.aspx). I'm getting an error on this line:

```
Dim score As Master.PasswordScore = Master.CheckStrength(txtPassVal)
```

The error is:

```
 Type 'Master.PasswordScore' is not defined.
```

Here is the full code of relevance:

Master Class:

```
Public Enum PasswordScore
    Blank = 0
    TooShort = 1
    RequirementsNotMet = 2
    VeryWeak = 3
    Weak = 4
    Fair = 5
    Medium = 6
    Strong = 7
    VeryStrong = 8
End Enum

Public Function CheckStrength(ByVal password As String) As PasswordScore
    Dim score As Int32 = 0

    If password.Length < 1 Then
        Return PasswordScore.Blank
    End If

    If password.Length < 8 Then
        Return PasswordScore.TooShort
    End If

    If password.Contains("password") Or password.Contains("12345678") Then
        Return PasswordScore.RequirementsNotMet
    End If

    If password.Length >= 8 Then
        score += 2
    End If

    If password.Length >= 12 Then
        score += 1
    End If

    If Regex.IsMatch(password, "/\d+/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript) Then
        'Contains a number
        score += 1
    End If

    If Regex.IsMatch(password, "/[a-z]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript) Then
        'Contains a lowercase letter
        score += 1
    End If

    If Regex.IsMatch(password, "/[A-Z]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript) Then
        'Contains an uppercase letter
        score += 1
    End If

    If Regex.IsMatch(password, "/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,£,(,)]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript) Then
        'Contains special character
        score += 2
    End If

    Return CType(score, PasswordScore)
End Function
```

Using the code in another class:

```
    Dim score As Master.PasswordScore = Master.CheckStrength(txtPassVal)
    Dim i As Int32 = CType(score, Int32)

    If i < 4 Then
        lblMsg.Text = "Password does not meet minimum security requirements."
        lblPasswordStrength.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf i > 3 Then
        lblPasswordStrength.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.DarkGreen
    End If
    lblPasswordStrength.Text = score.ToString()
```

It says it is not defined while it is. Any reason why it wouldn't give me access to it?

Comment: Is everything in the same namespace?

Comment: @MikeCheel I believe so, I call functions from Master elsewhere in the code and they work fine. Calling the Enum is the problem here it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the function like this

```
Dim score As Master.PasswordScore = Master.CheckStrength(txtPassVal)
```

Define the 'CheckStrength' function as 'Shared':

```
Public Shared Function CheckStrength(ByVal password As String) As PasswordScore
```

**Edit:** I would suggest you to move the Enum 'PasswordScore' outside the class `Master` and then access it like this:

```
 Dim score As PasswordScore = Master.CheckStrength(txtPassVal)
```

**Edit 2:**

```
Public Class Master
Public Shared Function CheckStrength(ByVal password As String) As PasswordScore
    Dim score As Int32 = 0

    If password.Length < 1 Then
        Return PasswordScore.Blank
    End If

    If password.Length < 8 Then
        Return PasswordScore.TooShort
    End If

    If password.Contains("password") Or password.Contains("12345678") Then
        Return PasswordScore.RequirementsNotMet
    End If

    If password.Length >= 8 Then
        score += 2
    End If

    If password.Length >= 12 Then
        score += 1
    End If

    If Regex.IsMatch(password, "/\d+/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript) Then
        'Contains a number
        score += 1
    End If

    If Regex.IsMatch(password, "/[a-z]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript) Then
        'Contains a lowercase letter
        score += 1
    End If

    If Regex.IsMatch(password, "/[A-Z]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript) Then
        'Contains an uppercase letter
        score += 1
    End If

    If Regex.IsMatch(password, "/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,£,(,)]/", RegexOptions.ECMAScript) Then
        'Contains special character
        score += 2
    End If

    Return CType(score, PasswordScore)
End Function
End Class

Public Enum PasswordScore
    Blank = 0
    TooShort = 1
    RequirementsNotMet = 2
    VeryWeak = 3
    Weak = 4
    Fair = 5
    Medium = 6
    Strong = 7
    VeryStrong = 8
End Enum
```

Comment: OK I changed that but I am still getting the error that Master.PasswordScore is undefined.

Comment: Originally I had it outside of the main class but then the function couldn't see it.

Comment: @Dan: Make sure it's in the same namespace but not in the same class. Then it should work perfectly.
However, if it still does not work hover over the 'PasswordScore' in your Master-Class and maybe there is an autosuggestion of how to solve the problem. ;)

Comment: OK trying this out, will let you know shortly. Thanks,

Comment: @Dan: does it look exactly like in 'Edit2'? (Note Public Class - End Class)

Comment: I see what I did now. Bigger issue than just this isolated instance - but you found it. Thanks!